# MySQL subquery to pull values by fieldname after join

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

i'm trying to create a join in MySQL which will pull in values from another table based on a fieldname. I have these 2 tables:

TABLE_MAIN:

| ID | EVENTID | FIELDNAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | FIELD1 |
| 2 | 1 | FIELD2 |
| 3 | 1 | FIELD3 |
| 4 | 2 | FIELD1 |
| 5 | 3 | FIELD2 |

TABLE_FIELDS:

| EVENTID | FIELD1 | FIELD2 | FIELD3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Some value | text | value |
| 2 | foo | bar | text |
| 3 | differentValue | more | text |

I'm trying to create something like below which i obviously cant do with a normal join:

| ID | EVENTID | FIELDNAME | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | FIELD1 | Some value |
| 2 | 1 | FIELD2 | text |
| 3 | 1 | FIELD3 | value |
| 4 | 2 | FIELD1 | foo |
| 5 | 3 | FIELD2 | more |

Ive started doing a simple join like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE MAIN LEFT JOIN TABLE_FIELDS ON TABLE_MAIN.EVENTID = TABLE_FIELDS.EVENTID
```

This however pulls in the full table, how would I be able to only pull in the field thats specify in the fieldname?
Thanks!
Robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `case` expressions as well as `join`:

```
select m.*,
       (case when m.fieldname = 'FIELD1' then f.field1
             when m.fieldname = 'FIELD2' then f.field2
             when m.fieldname = 'FIELD3' then f.field3
        end) as value
from table_main m left join
     table_fields f
     on m.eventid = f.eventid;
```

You should really fix your data model so you can use a join.  If the second field had each value in a separate *row*, you could just use a regular join.

Comment: Is there a way to do the case expressions for all fields automatically? I have hundreds of them...EDIT: the column name is exactly the same name as specified in the FIELDNAME field

Comment: @robs . . . You can construct the queries using a spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks, i'm hoping there is a way to do this dynamically somehow. If I add / remove a field I would have to change the underlying query each time if I hard-code every line

Comment: @robs . . . The values should be stored in rows, not columns.

Comment: I'm clearly not a database expert haha. But thanks, I figured out I can probably create a constructor with a prior query that just dumps out all the field names and creates that case when statement for me since it looks like theres no other way of doing it without restructuring the db

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to run dynamic SQL, although I would definitely not recommend it unless you had to.  I would take Mr. Linoff's suggestion that you rework the database structure so that you can avoid it.  However, here is how you can generate Mr. Linoff's query dynamically:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
    "select m.*, (case ",
    group_concat(distinct CONCAT("WHEN m.fieldname = '", FIELDNAME, "' then f.", FIELDNAME) SEPARATOR " "),
    " end) as value ",
    " from TABLE_MAIN m left join "
    " TABLE_FIELDS f "
    " on m.eventid = f.eventid; "
) INTO @stmt
FROM TABLE_MAIN;

SELECT @stmt;
PREPARE stmt FROM @stmt;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

I can't provide a SQL fiddle to demonstrate, because I don't know of a fiddle that allows dynamic sql to execute.  I did test it locally with your sample data, producing this:

[image]

Again, don't do this.  Sometimes it's unavoidable, but I think you could probably adjust your structure more easily than you can deal with dynamic SQL.  I realize this isn't a good solution, and I don't recommend it.